What permissions/roles do my account need to create new containers in a cosmos db?
According to this document, you just can create a container. But that is certainly not true.
I did some search and asked chatbot, and they seems to confirm that I need these roles for my account to create new contaienrs.

Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor
Cosmos DB Operator

I have created an account with these two roles, and have create a cosmos db manually. But my application using this account still cannot create new containers. It got 403 error when calling the CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync method.
What role/permission am I missing for my account?
Thanks

Assign the "Cosmos DB Account Contributor" role to your account, this role will allow you to create containers along with managing the Cosmos DB account’s resources.

Could you share which 403 error it was showing.

Sorry, I gave up and used TF to create containers manually.

Assign Cosmos DB Operator role to your application (maybe you are using sp to invoke the request?)
The actually action you need is Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/tables/containers/entities/create, But Microsoft does not provide such fine-grained roles， and if you check the Cosmos DB operator details

    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Cosmos DB Operator",
        "description": "Lets you manage Azure Cosmos DB accounts, but not access data in them. Prevents access to account keys and connection strings.",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/*",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
                    "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
                    "Microsoft.Support/*",
                    "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/joinViaServiceEndpoint/action"
                ],

the container entity create action is included in  "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/*"

Yes, I have Cosmos DB Operator assigned to that account. I mentioned in my OP. I am using a User Managed Identity in my AKS.

@DavidS. Cosmos DB Operator role with User Managed Identity should works here, it's weird.

I read many posts and asked multiple chatbots. They all point in the same direction. The only thing I am not certain about is that I don't manage that cluster. There could be other restrictions added unintentionally, and the error message was not clear about what blocked me.
